# how to do validation in joined table in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Any way to make `check_box` tag mandatory option in ruby on rails.

This is my shop view code(show.html.slim)

```
StandardSize.all.each do |s|
          li.checkbox.size-list
            label
              = f.check_box :standard_sizes_id_in, {multiple: true}, s.id, nil
              = s.name
```

I want to make this field mandatory when i click  submit.
This is a joined table also.

My model like this :

```
class ProductLineItemOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :line_item
  belongs_to :standard_size
end
```

Comment: @Norlihazmey thanks for edit

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043001/rails-3-how-to-make-the-user-choose-at-least-one-checkbox-in-a-form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043001/rails-3-how-to-make-the-user-choose-at-least-one-checkbox-in-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

If your check box is database attribute, then you can add model validation

```
validates :your_attr, acceptance: true
```

refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html